# Are predicted probabilities from glm models probabilities of 0 or 1?

Tags: r, glm

My response variable, `status` has two values, 1 for alive, 0 for dead.

I have built a model such as this one `model<- glm(status ~., train_data, family='binomial')`. I use `predict(model, test_data, type = 'response')`, which gives me a vector of predicted probabilities, like this:

```
0.02  0.04  0.1
```

Are these probabilities of someone being alive (i.e. `status == 1`) or someone being dead (i.e. `status == 0`)?

I'm pretty sure it's probabilities of someone being alive, but **is this always the case**? Is there a way to specify this directly in the `predict()` function?

Comment: The probability of `status == 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?binomial`:

> For the ‘binomial’ and ‘quasibinomial’ families the response can
> be specified in one of three ways:

> 1. As a factor: ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not
>    having the first level (and hence usually of having the
>    second level).

> 2. As a numerical vector with values between ‘0’ and ‘1’,
>    interpreted as the proportion of successful cases (with the
>    total number of cases given by the ‘weights’).

> 3. As a two-column integer matrix: the first column gives the
>    number of successes and the second the number of failures.

If `status` is numeric with values of 0 or 1, the "total number of cases" is assumed to be 1 (i.e., each observation is the failure (0) or success (1) of a single individual). (The probability is *always* "probability of 1", i.e. 0 always means "failure" and 1 always means "success".)

There is no way to change this in `predict()`, as far as I know: if you wanted to flip the probabilities you would need to use `1-status` rather than `status` as your response variable.

Comment: Thank you. So as long as the response variable is numeric with 0s and 1s, the model will always assume 0 to be failure and 1 to be a success, and the outputted predicted probabilities will always be the probabilities of success (i.e. probabilities of 1)?

Comment: Yes ............